# Perl pack template 'a' repetition

Tags: perl, pack

I need to extract a series of two-chars (which I'm passing to an unpack as they are really a strange form of BCD's). I'm current use:

```
my @whatever = unpack('a2 a2 a2 a2 a2 a2 a2', get_bcd_string());
```

It appears that I can't use something like `[6]` as a repetition factor with `a2`, but I would like to make sure.

I realize I could just extract using `a12` into a string and split the string, but I'm trying to learn if I could use unpack more effectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick:

```
unpack '(a2)6'
```

If you simply want to unpack the whole string, you can use the following instead:

```
unpack '(a2)*'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. I feel silly having missed that, but I appreciate your help.